# Eclipse LogCat window is not empty, but blank

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I am debugging an android app on a device and the LogCat window is blank, but not empty. What I mean by that is there is a scroll bar that looks like stuff is being added to the window, and I can indeed click on a line in the window and it highlights green. Just there is no text, or the text is white.

I really suspect Eclipse colors, but how can I check to see if it is actually a color issue (white on white)?

Yes, I can scroll the blank area.

Comment: What eclipse version and OS platform are you running on?  I get this same issue on Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse 4.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running on Ubuntu and you're using Eclipse Luna, you should take a look at this:  http://www.kaibader.de/fix-eclipse-luna-display-on-ubuntu-14-04/

There are a number of issues with GTK and Eclipse Luna that cause problems, including (for me at least) the one you describe.  The recommended solution at the link is to set some environment variables prior to the launch of Eclipse:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

Comment: just a FYI, you don't have to export these in your environment if only eclipse is acting up. I changed my /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop file (may be different location for you) with the following Exec= line:
    Exec=env SWT_GTK3=0 /usr/bin/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit colors in eclipse. I suggest poking around in the user preferences.

It may be good to double check you're not outputting only line breaks in the code.

Comment: It was working, so it's not line breaks. Even so, the application, tag , time fields would still show some content.

Comment: That's very interesting. I'm assuming you already poked around in the user preferences. And by 'content', you mean by readable text? Has restarting your IDE done anything?

Comment: Yes. And I restarted everything, rebooted. It's persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on (selecting) one of the 'blank' lines, and then clicking the 'Export Selected Items to Text File' button (a floppy disk) to the top right of the LogCat box. See whether the file contains anything. If it does, there is probably a colour issue; go to Preferences - Android - LogCat - Colours to change them.

Comment: I don't have that option only "Find..." and "Filter similar messages..."

Comment: You highlight the entry first, and then click on the little floppy disk in the top right corner.

Comment: Thanks, I found the colors area, they are all set to defaults. Still nothing is showing.

Comment: Whit does the output file say?

Comment: The output file is valid. The random one was "07-14 12:25:54.534: I/wpa_supplicant(1004): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED"

Comment: Check in the other colour settings. In Eclipse preferences, in filter, type color or colour, and check all listed settings.

Comment: It could be to do with the column sizing - try and make them all larger.